# How to inspect variables in the current scope in Hugo?

Tags: hugo

I'm trying to see what variables are available under "the dot".

According to [the docs](https://gohugo.io/templates/template-debugging/), `{{ printf "%#v" . }}` is what I'm looking for.

But it only seems to print a bunch of memory adresses.

For instance, in a place where the dot contains `.Params` and a bunch of other variables, this is what `{{ printf "%#v" . }}` yields:

```
&hugolib.pageState{pageOutputs:[]*hugolib.pageOutput{(*hugolib.pageOutput)(0xc0008cad80),
(*hugolib.pageOutput)(0xc0008cafc0)},
pageOutput:(*hugolib.pageOutput)(0xc0008cad80),
pageCommon:(*hugolib.pageCommon)(0xc00052b400)}
```

I'm not sure what that is, but it doesn't mention what is available in the current context.

Comment: [This post](https://regisphilibert.com/blog/2018/02/hugo-the-scope-the-context-and-the-dot/) does not answer your question, but you may find it interesting to read: it doesn't answer the question "how to inspect the dot", but it gives elements that might make this inspection unnecessary as it helps to understand the scope functioning of that dot in Hugo (at least, it helped me :) ).

Comment: Thanks, I did read this post and it is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I asked the same question in [Hugo's discourse community](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/how-to-inspect-variables-in-the-current-scope-in-hugo/28766) and Bjørn Erik Pedersen (creator of Hugo) suggested the following:

```
 {{ debug.Dump . }}
```

and

```
 {{ . | jsonify (dict "indent" " ") }}
```

I've had more luck with the latter.

Comment: This is pretty sad. Considering how crummy the docs are, some introspection functions would go a long way.